# CRT certificate for CosmosDB on Ubuntu not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure-cosmosdb, ubuntu-18.04, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I'm running CosmosDB emulator on docker on Ubuntu 18.04 following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#consume-endpoint-ui).

However, I can't seem to get the SSL certificate to work. Even after following the specific instruction in the tutorial, I still get a "potential security risk" from Firefox and Chrome.

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143526/make-trusted-self-signed-certificate-not-register-as-self-signed-i-e-trusted

It seems the Microsoft documentation is missing a step.